# use logical array to get the position of a combination of string from a cell array in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, indexing

Is there a better way of getting the `position` of `two` `strings` from a `cell array`? To illustrate my point, please find below an example:

```
fruittbl{1,1} = 'banana'
fruittbl{2,1} = 'mango'
fruittbl{3,1} = 'banana'
fruittbl{4,1} = 'peach'
fruittbl{5,1} = 'banana'

fruittbl{1,2} = 'green'
fruittbl{2,2} = 'red'
fruittbl{3,2} = 'yellow'
fruittbl{4,2} = 'green'
fruittbl{5,2} = 'red'

f= 'banana'; c = 'yellow'

idx_f = cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, f),fruittbl(:,1))
idx_c = cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, c),fruittbl(:,2))
lookup_idx = [idx_f idx_c]  % logical array

lookup_idx =

 1     0
 0     0
 1     1
 0     0
 1     0
```

Here I am interested in getting the `values` of `indices` where `lookup_idx = [1,1]`. This amounts to searching the position of `banana` `&&` `yellow` in `fruittbl`: `(3,3)`.

Unfortunately, an attempt to use `lookup_idx = [find(lookup_idx(:,1)>0) & find(lookup_idx(:,2)>0)]` is incorrect.

Thanks in advance

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ismember` and `categorical`...

```
idx = ismember( categorical( fruittbl ), {'banana','yellow'}, 'rows' )
```

Output:

```
>> idx
  0
  0
  1
  0
  0
```

So row 3 (`find(idx)`) is the row in `fruittbl` equal to `{'banana','yellow'}`. You have to use `categorical` because `ismember` is not defined for cell arrays and the `rows` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
>> result = ismember(fruittbl(:,1),'banana') & ismember(fruittbl(:,2),'yellow')

result =

  5×1 logical array

   0
   0
   1
   0
   0

>> fruittbl(result,1)

ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {'banana'}

>> fruittbl(result,2)

ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {'yellow'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Actually, i was looking for something that retrieves `[row_idx_f, row_idx_c] = [3,3]` corresponding in fact to `(3*1)` for `banana` and `(3*2)` for `yellow`.

Comment: In my code, [row_idx_f, row_idx_c] = deal(find(result)). In your code [row_idx_f, row_idx_c] = deal(find(idx_f&idx_c)). I think.